# why we use * args and **kwargs in super.save()

Tags: python, django

As I know, `*args` is a tuple, and `**kwargs` is a dictionary
and the `super.save()` is used to override the built-in save method and to ensure that the `save()` is called

but I can't understand why we use in here as parameters **

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
  super.save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of \*args and \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs)

Comment: *args is not a tuple

Comment: @PCM OP is right `args` is converted to a tuple, or in better words all extra positional arguments are packed into a tuple and passed as `args` because we write `*args`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
You pass `*args` and `**kwargs` because your `super.save()` method accepts these arguments and it has to be passed to the reference for it to properly get executed without errors.

**Long Explanation:**
Think your `super()` is a gateway to the inherited class, you can call the methods of the parent class via `super()`. When you say that you want to override something in the parent method you necessarily only want to add to what the existing method is providing.

Like this:

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
  self.request.user = get_current_logged_in_user() <--- Some validation or cleaning you want to do here.
  super.save(*args,**kwargs)
```

If you want to completely discourage all the implementation of that `save()` method from the parent class you just remove the `super.save(*args,**kwargs)` inside your def `save()`, but now you will have to implement your custom solution on how the `save()` method should be handled
Which can be opening a database connection, validating the data coming in, firing a query to save the data inside the database, committing the change to the database, and finally closing the database connection.

```
def save(self):
   # Open a db connection with url, user, password of your db
   # Validate the incoming data
   # Query the db
   # Commit the query
   # Close db connection
```